# Why use data-role="navbar" in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, custom-data-attribute

I'm using jQuery mobile to build a simple web app and I want to add a navigation bar common to all pages.

I've found [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/navbar/footer-persist-a.html) great example, which led me to this question: do I really need the attribute  data-role="navbar"?

Because it adds unnecessary html and css to my code, obligating me to override all these unnecessary styles.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the need for data-role="navbar". This page here might help: [jQuery Mobile Data Attributes](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html).

It looks like it might only be needed for styling.